# Showing that the linear transformation of an elementary/Jordan measurable set is Jordan measurable

Tags: measure-theory, linear-transformations

This question involves Exercise 1.1.11 in Tao's *Introduction to Measure Theory*, which I'm currently self-studying as a senior undergraduate.

For (1), Tao states that previous exercises show that $L(E)$ is Jordan measurable if $E$ is an elementary set, but I can't see how to apply them. I'm fine with the other part of (1).

For (2), I also don't really know how to start this. I feel like this will be clearer once I understand how to show that $L(E)$ is Jordan measurable for elementary $E$.

For (3), I'm guessing that I need to show that $D = |\det L|$ for elementary $L$ first and then reduce $L$ to a product of elementary matrices (and potentially an 'extra' matrix $A$ that can't be reduced further), but I'm not sure how to proceed after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assume $L$ is invertible, otherwise $L(E)$ can be upper-bounded by an elementary set with measure $0$.

For (1), to show $L(E)$ is Jordan measurable, you only need to show that, given a box $B$, $L(B)$ is a compact convex polytope (exercise 1.1.9).

For (2), $E$ can be approximated by elementary sets $A$ and $B$ from within and from without, then you can find elementary sets $A' \subset L(A)$ and $L(B) \subset B'$ that can approximate $L(E)$.

For (3), my understandings of the "alternatively" part of the hint in the book is that you can use polar decomposition to get $L = PU$, where $P$ is a SPD matrix, which can be factorized into $O^T\Lambda O$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal, $O$ and $U$ are orthogonal. You can use unit ball to show that the constant $D$ for $O$ or $U$ is $1$, and use box to show that $D$ for $\Lambda$ is $|\det(\Lambda)|$, so $D$ for $L$ is $|\det(L)|$

Answer (score 0):

pf: (1). Let $B := \prod_{i=1}^{d}[a_i,b_i]$ be a closed box. Then B can be written as $\bigcap_{i=1}^d\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d: x \cdot e_i \in [a_i,b_i]\}$. Let $[L] \in M_{d \times d}(\mathbb{R})$ be the matrix representation of $L$. $\forall x \in B$, $[L]x^T = \begin{pmatrix}r_1 \cdot x\\r_2 \cdot x \\\vdots\\r_d \cdot x\end{pmatrix}$, where $r_i = \begin{pmatrix}r_{i1} r_{i2} \dots\ r_{id}\end{pmatrix}=\sum_{j=1}^d{r_{ij}e_{j}}$ is the $i^{th}$ row of $[L]$. Hence $y_{i}:=r_{i} \cdot x=\sum_{j=1}^d{r_{ij}(x \cdot e_{j})} \in [a'_{i},b'_{i}]$ for some $a'_{i} \leqslant b'_{i}$ and every $1 \leqslant i \leqslant d$. Thus we have: $L(B)=\{[L]x^T:x\in B\}=\bigcap_{i=1}^d\{y \in \mathbb{R}^d:y_{i}=y \cdot e_{i} \in [a'_{i},b'_{i}]\}$(after transpose), which is a polytope and hence Jordan measurable by exercise 9. Since elementary sets are finite union of disjoint boxes, they are Jordan measurable by boolean closure.

Use the notation in exercise $3$, let $m' : \varepsilon(\mathbf{R}^d) \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^+$ be s.t $m'(E):=m(L(E))$. We first assume that $L$ is singular. Then $[L]$ will have a row(say the $i^{th}$ row) consists entirely of $0$ in its' RREF. Containing $L(E)$ in a box whose $i^{th}$ component is $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ and taking $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ gives that $m(L(E))=0=0m(E)=|\det L|m(E)$. Hence we assume that $L$ is invertible hereafter. Let $E_1$, $E_2 \in \varepsilon(\mathbf{R}^d)$ with $E_1 \cap E_2 = \emptyset$, then $m'(E_1 \cup E_2)=m(L(E_1 \cup E_2))=m(L(E_1) \cup L(E_2))=m(L(E_1)) + m(L(E_2))=m'(E_1) + m'(E_2)$. $\forall x \in \mathbf{R}^d$, $m'(x+E_1)=m(L(x+E_1))=m(L(x)+L(E_1))=m(L(E_1))=m'(E_1)$. Clearly $m' \geq 0$. So $m'$ obeys non-negativity, finite additivity and translation invariance, which implies by exercise 3 that $\exists D \in \mathbf{R}^+, m'(E)=m(L(E))=Dm(E)$.

(2). If $E$ is Jordan measurable. By exercise 2 there exist elementary sets $A \subset E \subset B$ s.t $m(B \backslash A)=m(B)-m(A) \leq \epsilon$. Since $L(A) \subset L(E) \subset L(B)$, by monotonicity $Dm(A)=m(L(A)) \leq m(L(E)) \leq m(L(B))=Dm(B)$. Also $Dm(A) \leq Dm(E) \leq Dm(B)$ since $D \geq 0$. Hence $|m(L(E)) - Dm(E)| \leq D(m(B) - m(A)) \leq D \epsilon \rightarrow 0$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. ie, $m(L(E))=Dm(E)$.

(3). From exercise 3, we know that $D=m(L([0,1))^d)$. Start with $L$ be elementary. If $L$ switches two rows, then $\det L=-1$ and $D=m([0,1)^d)=1=|\det L|$. If $L$ scales a row by some constant $k$, then $\det L=k$ and $D=m([0,1) \times \dots \times [0,k) \times \dots \times [0,1))=k$(assuming WLOG $k>0$)=$|\det L|$.

Now consider when $L$ adds row $i$ to row $j$. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n>0$. Define $\overline{B_i}:=[\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}) \times [\frac{i-1}{n},1+\frac{i}{n})$,and $\underline{B_i}:=[\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}) \times [\frac{i}{n},1+\frac{i-1}{n})$. Then the collections $(\overline{B_i})_{1  \leqslant i \leqslant n}$ and $(\underline{B_i})_{1  \leqslant i \leqslant n}$ upper and lower bounds the set$\{(x,x+y):x, y \in [0,1)\}$, resp. Denote $E=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\underline{B_i}$ and $F=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\overline{B_i}$, we have $m(E)=1-\frac{1}{n}$ and $m(F)=1+\frac{1}{n}$. In particular we have: $E \times B^{d-2} \subset \{(x,x+y):x, y \in [0,1)\} \times B^{d-2} =  S_{1i}S_{2j}L([0,1)^d)\subset F \times B^{d-2}$, where $S_{ij}$ is the linear map switching the $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ row and $B^{d-2}$ the $d-2$ dimensional unit box. By monotonicity, exercise 4 and above, we thus have: $1-\frac{1}{n} \leq m(L([0,1))^d) \leq 1+\frac{1}{n}$, $\forall n > 0 \in \mathbb{N}$. This implies that $D=1=|\det L|$.

Finally, Let $L = \prod_{i=1}^mL_{i}$ be the factorization of $L$ into elementary maps, then $D=m(L([0,1))^d)=m(\prod_{i=1}^mL_{i}([0,1)^d))=(\prod_{i=1}^m|\det L_{i}|)m([0,1)^d)=|\det L| \cdot 1=|\det L|$.